# Second scroll bar appears inside a div (behaves like an iframe)

Tags: html, css, iframe, scrollbar

Somehow a second scrollbar appears in my development page

http://topdodavatel.cz/defakto/produkty/stoly/

Do you have any idea why this happens? I believe the content should automatically fit into the page and only one scrollbar would be necessary.

Here is how the problem looks like

[image: Problem with 2 scroll bars]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

in your body, html CSS. 
Should be fine after this.

Comment: Thank you @Math3w, this helps! But when removed, a horizontal appears in responsive layout (480px width).

Comment: I just added the value overflow-x: hidden;  to a container element instead of whole html and looks good so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. iframe height set based on content height. so scroll not show

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function resizeIframe(obj) {
        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
      }
    </script>

    <iframe  src="http://stackoverflow.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' />
```

Comment: Thank you Enemy! But it is not in reality an iframe, just a div that had that iframe-like scroll bar :)